# Can't create Git Repository in old project

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

I'm trying to add git to my project.

I am trying to create a Git Repository: Source Control -> New Git Repositories... I get an alert that I have already created.

[image]

But I have nothing in these tabs and I can't do any further actions through the menu.

[image]

In the settings I have this set up:
[image]

In terminal:
[image]

I have Xcode version 13.1. The project is posted in the AppStore, I can't start it again.
I just need to create Repository. And it is not being created.

Comment: Special behavior.. Try to restart Xcode and if that doesn't help, delete the existing `.git` folder and create a **really** new git repository in the steps you mentioned.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Restarted Xcode, the computer - did not help. Where to me .find git? It is not in the project folder.

Comment: Make in *rent* folder `ls -la` and there you will find the `.git` folder. To delete this folder, run `rm -rf .git`. But do this only, if you are sure that you don‘t need anything from this folder (branches, changes, history…)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I've been trying to figure this out for two hours. I opened the hidden files on the computer and found .git in the project. I deleted it and everything was created! Thanks!